# How to get Binding-Context on creating DataTemplate

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, collectionview, itemssource

Is there a way to get the Binding-Context itself in an enumerated template?

```
this.CollectionView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    var view = new SubView();
    view.SetBinding(SubView.SourceProperty, new Binding()
    {
        Source = ??? // <- here
    });
    
    return view;
};
```

Note:
`Path = "."` works fine on Android. but on iOS, the source is duplicated.
I have already checked that there are no duplicates in CollectionView.ItemsSource.

Comment: According to your code, am I not clear what problem did you encounter?  If you want to use collectionview binding by code behind, you can take a look: [xamarin.forms collectionview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#define-item-appearance)

Comment: Thanks reply, Cherry Bu. The Action in the argument of DataTemplate constructor were being executed as many times as the number of elements. So I imagined that there will be a way to pass the element itself as argument to the Action.

Comment: Why do you do this? For collectionview.ItemTemplate, I usually use like [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data), not sure if you want to use [relative binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings).

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to the platform I hope I can help.
I understand that you want to get the BindingContext of each element in the list. If I am interpreting correctly, then this is what you can do:

```
public partial class NotificationsPage : ContentPageBase
{
    public NotificationsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CollectionView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            return new Item();
        });
    }
}

public class Item : ContentView
{
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        if (BindingContext is ItemModel item)
        {
            var name = item.Name;
        }
    }
}

public class ItemModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

DataTemplate does not contain an accessible BindingContext, the BindingContext is passed to the element containing the DataTemplate.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, AlexDev. I understood that it's impossible.